# In SVN, what is the best practice with a branch that will never be merged?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I am working on a project with my colleague.  Its hosted in an SVN repository.    We use the classic trunk, branch, tag paradigm.

I recently created a branch off the trunk to add a small new feature.  While I was working on this new feature, he had some free time and decided to take a crack it as well. He made all his changes locally. We did a code review and we both like his version better, so we will check in his local changes to the trunk.  Now there is no use for my branch.

Question: What is the SVN best practice with the unmerged branch?  Do we just leave it as is?  Should it get any special notation?  Should it be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the branch won't need to be referenced in the future, just delete it with a commit message that explains the situation. You can always get it back if you really need it. There's no need to keep the `HEAD` revision cluttered with obsolete and unused copies.

Comment: As you said, I deleted the branch and noted the code we are going to use in the trunk.  This will keep our repository cleaner and easier to read.